# Remove and blacklist [ad]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

Recently [all questions tagged [ad] were re-tagged as either [active-directory] or [advertisement]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53707/merge-ad-into-active-directory).

As I understand it, while all those questions were re-tagged, [ad] could still be used in the future and rear its ugly head once again. For the sake of [disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AD_%28disambiguation%29) could [ad] be blacklisted?

### Edit

Has this been attended to? There seem to be no more [ad] questions.

Comment: Everything has been retagged out of `[ad]`, but there are currently no tag synonyms in place.